# Finding second moment without standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Just want to make sure I'm doing this correctly

Question:

The weight limit of a scale is 5.25 kilograms. W is normally distributed with mean weight 5.15 kilograms and standard deviation $\sigma$.
The probability that W exceeds the weight limit of the scale is 0.3228.

What is the value of the second moment?

Attempt:

$P(Z>\frac{5.25-5.15}{\sigma}) = .3228$

$P(Z<\frac{5.25-5.15}{\sigma}) = 1- .3228 = .6772$

$\frac{5.25-5.15}{\sigma} = .46$

$5.25-5.15 = .46\sigma$

$\sigma = \frac{.1}{.46} = .21739$

$\sigma^2 = .21739^2 = .04725$

$E(W^2) = \sigma^2 + (E(W))^2 = .0475 + 5.15^2$

$E(W^2) = 26.5697 \approx 26.570$

Comment: Your approach is good but I haven't checked your calculations. And it should be $E(W^2)$ in the end.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, just switched the variables but used the same idea.

Comment: Now it's wrong in the beginning :D Use any alphabet other than $W$ in the beginning, because $W$ is your original random variable. You've converted it into standard normal by subtracting the mean and dividing by s.d. $Z$ is used to denote standard normal distribution.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but was the computation incorrect?

Comment: Do you want me to check your calculations? ;)

Comment: Sorry just need a second set of eyes. I believe I did this problem correctly, unless someone finds an error in my work.

Comment: It is correct..